# ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to connect to my VM instances using gcutil and keep getting the following:

```
ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com
```

Here is the command: `gcutil --service_version="v1beta16" --project="macro-truck-222" ssh  --zone="us-central1-a" "cheddar1"`

Comment: Have you authenticated your self to Google Compute Engine?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use gcutil against v1beta16 of the API, which has been turned off.  Please drop the --service_version=v1beta16 flag, and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Benson correctly states, **v1beta16** has been turned down as of **April 4th, 2014**. ([announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-announce/SgYrLQk6PJc)).

Before then, maybe you were using a proxy and you were hitting [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/issues/detail?id=91) issue?